# Getting an average in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am basically trying to get the average of of a column. So I need the sum of the column (Erosion12) divided by the total number of rows returned (count(BrandDescAbbr). Below is the code I have but it doesnt seem to be working.

```
declare @g table (GenProdIdent varchar(50) primary key )
insert @g
values ('44505080000310'),('44505080000320')

select BrandDescAbbr,
           12 as [Month],
           Erosion12 as Erosion,
           avg(Erosion12)
      from ErosionData2
     where GenProdIdent in (select GenProdIdent from @g)
  group by BrandDescAbbr,
           Erosion12
```

Comment: I am also going to need all of those different columns returned. I am not sure if the AVG function will work for this if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the grouping by `Erosion12`:

```
select BrandDescAbbr,
           12 as [Month],
           /*Erosion12 as Erosion,*/
           avg(Erosion12)
      from ErosionData2
     where GenProdIdent in (select GenProdIdent from @g)
  group by BrandDescAbbr
           /*, Erosion12*/
```

When you group by `Erosion12` all records will have the same value so an average is pointless.

Or, if you need all of the individual `Erosion12` values *and* the average within the group use a windowing function:

```
select BrandDescAbbr,
           12 as [Month],
           Erosion12 as Erosion
           AVG(Erosion12) OVER (PARTITION BY BrandDescAbbr)
      from ErosionData2
     where GenProdIdent in (select GenProdIdent from @g)
```

Comment: I ran that bottom code but the column that is supposed to show the average is still showing the same thing as the erosion12 column...

Comment: Are there other `Erosion12` values within that `BrandDescAbbr` (after filtering by `GenProdIdent`)?

Comment: No there are not. The genprodident is a primary key.

Comment: So you want the average of all items _including those not filtered by `GenProdIdent`_?

Comment: So I have this query and I basically want is to return the exact same values, except add another column to it called "Average". The average column should be calculated by summing the "Erosion" rows and then dividing it by how many rows there are that were returned, or how many different BrandDescAbbr. Dont worry about the GenProdIdent. Both are unique and both can be used to filter.

Comment: declare @g table (GenProdIdent varchar(50) primary key )
insert @g
values ('44505080000310'),('44505080000320')

select BrandDescAbbr,
           12 as [Month],
           Erosion12 as Erosion
      from ErosionData2
     where GenProdIdent in (select GenProdIdent from @g)

Comment: @user1049984 so just change the partition to `PARTITION BY 1`